# change icon when hover list

Tags: jquery, css

i have a list of items/menus, when i hover list (li), i want the icon to change according to which li i have hovered. how can i achieve this ?
hovering icon span will change the image using sprites. but i want to change it when i hover their respective li . Need Some idea please!

the html is below

```
<div class="short-menu">
   <ul class="sm-ul">
        <li><span class="search-icon"></span><span>Search</span></li>
        <li><span class="setting-icon"></span><span>settings</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the css

```
/* list icons */
.search-ico { width:40px; height:40px; display:block; background:url(../img/icons/search.png) 0px 0px;}
.search-ico:hover { background:url(../img/icons/search.png) 0px -39px;}
```

Comment: please share the css definitions also

Comment: Please share your code what you have tried?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure i get what you're asking, but it would be something like that

```
.sm-ul li:hover .search-icon
{
    background-position: *position of hovered icones*
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want the hover effect to be triggered by the li element but applied to the span element within that li?

If so, you can do this:

```
.sm-ul li:hover .search-icon{background:url(../img/icons/search_hover.png) 0px -39px;}
```

This means the hover is across the li but the effect happens on its child element. See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Y3mU/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="short-menu">
   <ul class="sm-ul">
        <li><span class="search-icon"></span><span>Search</span></li>
        <li><span class="setting-icon"></span><span>settings</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('li').mouseover(
     function(){
          var itemClass = $(this).find('span').attr('class');
      }
);
//And based on item's class you have in var itemClass you can do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try giving each <li> element an onmouseover attribute:

```
<li onmouseover="setHoverIcon(2)">List item 3</li>
```

where 2 corresponds to the icon (can be any number. In the javascript, you could write:

```
function setHoverIcon(i) {
    //Set the icon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:Jquery:

```
$("li").hover(
function () {
$(this).addClass("hover");
},
function () {
$(this).removeClass("hover");
}
);
```

Method 2: css:

```
li .search-icon:hover {
//change background(make icon as background image)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul.sm-ul li span{
        background-image: url("YOUR sprite image url");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block;
    }  
div.short-menu ul.sm-ul li span.search-icon:hover{
        background-position: -197px -44px; // change this position as per your img
    }
div.short-menu ul.sm-ul li span.search-icon {
        background-position: -197px 0; // change this position as per your img
    }
```